# Eclipse + JAVA: Checking which data members can be made final

Tags: java, eclipse, immutability, final

Is there a way in Eclipse to get a list of class data members that are not declared as final but can be declared as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a configurable "clean up" function, that will do all the work for you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the checkstyle plugin for Eclipse for this.

http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/screen_shots.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Findbugs eclipse plugin which will give you a report with all the obvious issues in your code. It also includes a list of variables which can be marked as final.

If you want you can modify findbugs to just display this as part of your report.

[Findbugs site](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

[Findbugs eclipse plugin](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html)